# Trigonometry project and questions

Tags: trigonometry

I have a question on a trig project that goes like this. The Leaning tower of Pisa, which is 177 feet tall, leans about 5.5 degrees from vertical. How far from the base of the tower will an object dropped from the tower land?

I started off by figuring out if i had to use sin, cos, or tan. I ended up getting tan because when i draw the picture its in a right triangle form. So the only known angles are 5.5 and 90 which is the adjacent on the triangle. The only side known is 177 which is the opposite on the triangle when I tried figuring it out.

I don't know what i am doing wrong or how to do it

Comment: Try drawing a diagram and using [SOHCAHTOA](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SOHCAHTOA.html)

Comment: Call the horizontal distance $x$.  Set up an equation in terms of $x$ using the given information.